# Configuring Warden with Grape API application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warden, grape-api

I have configured Warden in my Rails/Grape API app in `config/initializers/warden.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :password
end
```

(I'd share the `password` strategy code, but it really doesn't apply to this question. I have it stored at `config/initializers/warden/strategies/password.rb`.)

When I run an RSpec rquest spec with invalid login credentials:

```
describe 'session_tokens', type: :request do
  let!(:user)      { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:ip_address) { Faker::Internet.ip_v4_address }

  describe 'POST /' do
    context 'with invalid password' do
      before do
        post '/api/v1/session_tokens', email: user.email, password: "#{user.password}.", ip: ip_address
      end

      it 'is unsuccessful' do
        expect(response.code).to eql '401'
      end

      it 'has an "X-Error-Detail" header' do
        expect(response.header['X-Error-Detail']).to eql 'Invalid email or password.'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It gives me this error:

```
Failure/Error: post '/api/v1/session_tokens', email: user.email, password: "#{user.password}.", ip: ip_address
RuntimeError:
   No Failure App provided
```

For the life of me, I cannot get Warden to work correctly with Grape after reviewing examples online (for example, [dblock/grape_warden](https://github.com/dblock/grape_warden)). Most examples are simple and set the Grape app itself as the failure app.

When I do pass a module within my Grape app as the `failure_app`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :password
  manager.failure_app = -> (env) { API::V1::SessionTokens }
end
```

I get this error, even though I have a `post :unauthenticated` block in that module:

```
Failure/Error: post '/api/v1/session_tokens', email: user.email, password: "#{user.password}.", ip: ip_address
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `unauthenticated' for API::V1::SessionTokens:Class
```

The same happens when I move the `unauthenticated` definition to the root of my Grape app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to configure Warden within the Grape app itself instead of within a Rails initializer.

I removed `config/initializers/warden.rb` and put its contents within my Grape app as such:

```
module API
  module V1
    class Base < Grape::API
      mount API::V1::SessionTokens

      use Warden::Manager do |manager|
        manager.default_strategies :password
        manager.failure_app = API::V1::SessionTokens
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Works perfectly now!

Kudos to Jean Bahnik for [this file on GitHub](https://github.com/jeanbahnik/member_api_playground/blob/master/app/api/users_api.rb) in particular. I found this beautiful piece of code after almost giving up.